# and перед последним элементом массива и запятые до

Tags: php

Задача с codewars:

Ваша задача для завершения этого Ката — написать функцию, которая форматирует продолжительность, заданную в виде количества секунд, удобным для человека способом.

Функция должна принимать неотрицательное целое число. Если он равен нулю, он просто возвращает "now". В противном случае продолжительность выражается как комбинация years, days, hoursи minutes.seconds

Гораздо проще понять на примере:

- For seconds = 62, your function should return
  "1 minute and 2 seconds"
- For seconds = 3662, your function should return
  "1 hour, 1 minute and 2 seconds"
  Для целей этого Ката год равен 365 дням, а день равен 24 часам.

Обратите внимание, что пробелы важны.

Подробные правила
Результирующее выражение состоит из таких компонентов, как 4 seconds, 1 year, и т. д. Обычно это положительное целое число и одна из допустимых единиц времени, разделенные пробелом. Единица времени используется во множественном числе, если целое число больше 1.

Компоненты разделяются запятой и пробелом ( ", "). За исключением последнего компонента, который отделяется " and ", как если бы он был написан на английском языке.

Более значимые единицы времени будут происходить раньше, чем наименее значимые. Поэтому 1 second and 1 yearне правильно, а 1 year and 1 secondесть.

Разные компоненты имеют разную единицу измерения времени. Таким образом, нет повторяющихся единиц, как в 5 seconds and 1 second.

Компонент вообще не появится, если его значение равно нулю. Следовательно, 1 minute and 0 secondsнедействительно, но это должно быть просто 1 minute.

Единица времени должна использоваться «насколько это возможно». Это означает, что функция должна возвращать не 61 seconds, а 1 minute and 1 secondвместо этого. Формально продолжительность, указанная параметром компонента, не должна превышать любую допустимую более значащую единицу времени.

Ссылка: https://www.codewars.com/kata/52742f58faf5485cae000b9a/train/php

Может знает кто, как вставить и перед последним элементом? У меня вышло так:

Косяк нашла, этот array_merge не хочет 0 элементы выводить, так что вышло в это все:

```
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!

function format_duration() {
 $time = 62454;
    
  
  if ($time > 0){
  $years = intval($time / 365 / 24 / 60 / 60);
  $days = intval($time / 24 / 60 / 60) % 365;
  $hours = intval($time / 60 / 60) % 24;
  $minutes = intval($time / 60) % 60;
  $seconds = $time % 60;
   
   if ($years > 0){
      $yr = $years;
      $str_time = array($yr, ' year, ');
      //var_dump(implode(",", $str_time));
        echo implode( ' ', $str_time );
        $result = $str_time;
        echo implode($result);
   }   
       if ($days > 0){
      $ds = $days;
      $str_time1 = array($ds, ' day, ');
         //var_dump($str_time1);
         echo implode( ' ', $str_time1 );
         $result1 = $str_time1;
       }   
         if ($hours > 0){
      $hr = $hours;
     $str_time2 = array($hr, ' hour ');
     // var_dump($str_time2);
     echo implode( ' ', $str_time2 );
      $result2 = $str_time2;
         }  
         if ($minutes > 0){
      $mn = $minutes;
      $str_time3 = array($mn, ' minute ');
      //var_dump($str_time3);
      echo implode( ' ', $str_time3 );
      $result3 = $str_time3;
         } 
         if ($seconds > 0){
      $sc = $seconds;
      $str_time4 = array($sc, ' second');
     // var_dump($str_time4);
    echo implode( ' ', $str_time4 );
     $result4 = $str_time4;
    }


//$result5 = array_merge($str_time, $str_time1, $str_time2, $str_time3, $str_time4);
//echo implode($result5);

//if ($result5 > 0){
    //$all = end($result5);
//  while (next($result5 > 0)){
    //  echo " , ";
//  }
    
    
//}
//var_dump(implode(",", $array));


       
   
 // $str_time = $yr.' лет ' .$ds.' дней ' .$hr.' часа ' .$mn.' минут и '.$sc.' секунд' ;

    }else{
    return now;
  }
}

format_duration();
```

Я специально не убирала закоментированные строки.

Я пишу в стороннем редакторе, так как это удобнее мне, на самом сайте все выглядит так. Первый тест я прошла конечно, ура. Но у меня все еще не лепится and перед последним элементом и запятые до. Может знает кто, как это сделать?
codewars код:

```
function format_duration($time) {
 //$time = 36;
    
  
  if ($time > 0){
  $years = intval($time / 365 / 24 / 60 / 60);
  $days = intval($time / 24 / 60 / 60) % 365;
  $hours = intval($time / 60 / 60) % 24;
  $minutes = intval($time / 60) % 60;
  $seconds = $time % 60;
   
   if ($years > 0){
      $yr = $years;
      $str_time = array($yr, ' year, ');
      //var_dump(implode(",", $str_time));
        return implode( ' ', $str_time );
   }   
       if ($days > 0){
      $ds = $days;
      $str_time1 = array($ds, ' day, ');
         //var_dump($str_time1);
         return implode( ' ', $str_time1 );
       }   
         if ($hours > 0){
      $hr = $hours;
     $str_time2 = array($hr, ' hour ');
     // var_dump($str_time2);
     return implode( ' ', $str_time2 );
         }  
         if ($minutes > 0){
      $mn = $minutes;
      $str_time3 = array($mn, ' minute ');
      //var_dump($str_time3);
      return implode( ' ', $str_time3 );
         } 
         if ($seconds > 0){
      $sc = $seconds;
      $str_time4 = array($sc, 'second');
     // var_dump($str_time4);
     return implode( ' ', $str_time4 );
     
    }

//var_dump(implode(",", $array));


       
   
 // $str_time = $yr.' лет ' .$ds.' дней ' .$hr.' часа ' .$mn.' минут и '.$sc.' секунд' ;

    }else{
    return now;
  }
}
```

Comment: собирайте в массив, все элементы, кроме последнего implode(', '... и добавить ' and ' последний

Comment: splash58, звучит все хорошо. а как это сделать?

Comment: У меня тут раздельный вывод, так как array_merge не пихайет в массив пустые элементы. И это все.. усложняет наверное

Comment: замени последнюю запятую на `AND`  и дело с концом

Comment: вообще слей все значения в массив вида `['year' => $years,]` отфильтруй не нулевые. потом по ключам сформируй строки, потом слей с запятой, и замени последнюю на and в строке. Не надо этих костылей с `if > 0`

Comment: а `now` все же должно наверное быть `"now"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то у вас должно быть вида (код условный)

```
 // массив компонент времени, которые надо вывести
 // ключи сразу сделать соответствующими строкам, которые выводятся 
 $data = [
     'year' => ....,
     'day' => ....,
      ...
     'second' => ...., 
 ];

 // фомируем массив строк вида `1 year`, нулевые пропускаем
 $strings = [];
 foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
     if ($v) {
        $s = $v > 1 ? "s" : "";
        $strings[] = "{$v} {$k}{$s}";
     }
 }  
 // объедимняем в строку через запятую
 $msg = implode(', ', $strings);
 // ищем позицию _последнего_ вхождения запятой в строку
 $lastCommaPos = mb_strrpos($msg, ',');
 // и если она нашлась..    
 if ($lastCommaPos !== false) {
     // заменяем на `and`
     $msg = substr_replace($msg, " and", $lastCommaPos, 1);
 }

 return $msg;
```

Comment: забыли про единственное/множественно число и now

Comment: teran, спасибо вам огромное за помощь. Если у вас есть время, могли ы вы немного пояснить код? Как я поняла, вы записали все элементы в массив вначале, после нашли последний элемент этой строчкой:  $lastCommaPos = mb_strrpos($msg, ','); Гугл мне сказал, что это функция mb_strpos — Поиска позиции первого вхождения одной строки в другую, если вас не затруднит, вы не могли ы пояснить, что это значит? То есть он отслеживает когда последний раз был записан элемент и ставится на позицию До него?

Comment: Также..      'seconds' => $seconds,  - так можно было?!?!?!? Это сразу поянение секунды слово - секунды переменная? 

И тут..  $msg = substr_replace($msg, " and", $lastCommaPos, 1); а. или это получается значит, что оно просто показывается - это: $lastCommaPos - что вот эта строка последняя с помощью этой ф-ции mb_strrpos?

Comment: И еще вопрос. Чрезе костыли, как я делала изначально - совсем плохо? или из этого в итоге тоже можно было сделать более или менее с этой частью:  $msg = implode(',', $strings);
 $lastCommaPos = mb_strrpos($msg, ',');
 if ($lastCommaPos !== false) {
     $msg = substr_replace($msg, " and", $lastCommaPos, 1);
 }

Comment: splash58, с now то я разобралась быстро, а вот с множественным/ед. число.. сижу вот..

Comment: дополнил комментариями. Про множественное число, я что-ро пропустил это в вопросе, Там написано. что написание должно различаться для `1 year`, `2 yearS`. Поскольку логика тут предельно проста, то можно либо ифом это оформить, либо `$s = $v > 1 ? "s" : "";  .... "{$v} {$k}{$s}"`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!! ЯЯ сидела с ифами:)))

Comment: галку ткните, если пройдет

Comment: пасиба! Все доделала и прошло:))